# Select distinct value from row if condition exists

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am new to SQL and I am having trouble constructing a `SELECT` statement.

What I would like to do is select distinct parts that have a location of A1 if it exists. If a part has no locations of A1 I would like to select distinct material with no condition of location.

Is there a way to make this select statement 1 query or do I need to break it up in selecting the distinct condition true values and selecting the distinct condition false values?

Sample data:

```
+------+------+----------+
| PART | TYPE | Location |
+------+------+----------+
| A    |    1 | A1       |
| A    |    2 | A1       |
| A    |    1 | A2       |
| A    |    2 | A2       |
| B    |    1 | A2       |
| B    |    1 | A3       |
+------+------+----------+
```

Comment: Richard, I'd suggest you edit your question to add what the desired output should be, and how you get from the sample data to this output

Answer (score 2):

How about a little 2 in 1 using CTE?

```
;with cte as (
    select top 1 loc = 1
    from parts 
    where Location = 'A1'
)
select distinct Part --, Type, Location
from parts left join cte on 1=1
where loc is null or Location = 'A1';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select distinct t1.part 
from table t1 
where t1.Location = 'A1' 
      or not exists (select 1 from table where Location = 'A1')
```

Answer (score 2):

In simple words, it could be put as:

> If the table *has* the `A1` location, give me every distinct *`part`* that *is* the `A1` location. Otherwise give me every distinct *`part`* regardless of location.

Based on that, the query could be built like this:

```
WITH cte AS
  (
    SELECT
      *,
      TableHasA1 = COUNT(DISTINCT CASE Location WHEN 'A1' THEN 1 END) OVER (),
      RowIsA1    = CASE Location WHEN 'A1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM
      dbo.atable
  )
SELECT DISTINCT
  PART
FROM
  cte
WHERE
  TableHasA1 = RowIsA1
;
```

- The *`TableHasA1`* value will be the same for all the rows. It will be either 1 or 0 depending on whether `A1` rows are present in the table or not present. The *`RowIsA1`* value will be 1 for `A1` rows and 0 for non-`A1` rows.
- If *`TableHasA1`* is 1, then there will definitely be some rows for which *`RowIsA1`* is 1 as well – and `TableHasA1 = RowIsA1` will give only those rows, thus satisfying the first half of the problem description.
- If *`TableHasA1`* is 0, then *`RowIsA1`* will be 0 for all the rows – and so the same condition will this time match all the rows, which fulfils the other half of the problem description.